# MVC модель в JavaFX на пальцах

Tags: java, javafx

Можно очень просто "на пальцах" объяснить как пользоваться MVC моделью при построении GUI в JavaFX ? Какую структуру папок создавать и что в них пихать ? Было бы клева еще увидеть пример какой-нибудь работы с github, который продемонстрирует полному чайнику как не быдлокодить при использовании JavaFX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот хороший мануал по теме: http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/ru/part1/
Рассказано и про JavaFX и про FXML и про контроллеры и про биндинги (связывание пропертей) вроде было.
В общем - чудесный ресурс для освоения JavaFX.

Ну и про [JavaFX Scene Builder (Gluon)](http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/) не забудьте!

П.С.: В мануале работают с Eclipse. Я рекомендую **NetBeans**. Но это чисто моё **личное предпочтение**.

Comment: Я пробовал эти уроки в IntelliJ IDEA. В них используется Scene Builder для построения всего приложения. Но в других источниках он не используется вообще, почему так ?

Comment: Если отвечать на вопрос "Почему так?", то первым приходит в голову такое обоснование: ибо так возможно. JavaFX позволяет как использовать XML (FXML) шаблоны, так и не использовать их. Всё зависит от того, что будет удобным для разработчика.